# Indexing in Theano

Tags: theano, matrix-indexing

How can I index a matrix in Theano by a vector of indices?

More precisely, say that:

- *v* has type theano.tensor.vector (e.g. [0,2])
- *A* has type theano.tensor.matrix (e.g. [[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]])

The desired result is [[1,0,0], [0,0,1]].

I mention that my goal is to convert a list of indices into a matrix of one-hot row vectors, where the indices indicate the hot position. My initial attempt was to let A = theano.tensor.eye and index it using the vector of indices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
A[v]
```

It will do what you want.

Comment: I have tried this already, but I get an error message. I define *v = theano.tensor.vector()*, *A = theano.tensor.matrix()* and *indexed = A[v]*. The error message is the following: *TypeError: index must be integers*.

Comment: the list v, must be integers. Can you cast to to int like this: theano.tensor.cast(v, 'int64').

Comment: v = theano.tensor.lvector() gives you an integer 64 bit vector without the need to cast. Check types list here: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#all-fully-typed-constructors